# Why can't the 'special values' in the transportation fundamental diagrams always be determined?

Tags: transportation

Why can't the 'special values' in the transportation fundamental diagrams always be determined?  For example:
Why can't I always determine the Free-flow speed (A),
Capacity (B),
Critical density (B),
Speed at capacity (B),
Jam density (C) from the fundamental diagrams?

Is it because of lack of data?

[image]

Like why does the above diagram looks like that when it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Where does the data come from?  Add that to your question.

Comment: Perhaps some traffic won't ever meet the conditions needed to populate parts of the curve you want to see...